# Unable to plot dataframe using seaborn barplot

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I have been able to use pandas `groupby` to create a new `DataFrame` but I'm getting an error when I create a `barplot`.
The groupby command:

`invYr = invoices.groupby(['FinYear']).sum()[['Amount']]`

Which creates a new `DataFrame` that looks correct to me.

[image: New DataFrame invYr]

Running:

`sns.barplot(x='FinYear', y='Amount', data=invYr)`

I get the error:

`ValueError: Could not interperet input 'FinYear'`

It appears that the issue is related to the index, being FinYear but unfortunately I have not been able to solve the issue even when using `reindex`.

Comment: Try `data=invYr.reset_index()` to push the index back into a column.

Comment: The `DataFrame` has no index now and looks good, like a CSV that has just been imported but unfortunately the same error massage remains.

Comment: My guess would be that you are not reassigning the output of `invYr.reset_index()`. It's not an in-place operation, so it might print to the REPL and look like it "worked" but that's not what you're passing to `barplot`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

invoices = pd.DataFrame({'FinYear': [2015, 2015, 2014], 'Amount': [10, 10, 15]})
invYr = invoices.groupby(['FinYear']).sum()[['Amount']]

>>> invYr
         Amount
FinYear        
2014         15
2015         20
```

The reason that you are getting the error is that when you created `invYr` by grouping `invoices`, the `FinYear` column becomes the index and is no longer a column.  There are a few solutions:

1) One solution is to specify the source data directly. You need to specify the correct datasource for the chart.  If you do not specify a `data` parameter, Seaborn does not know which dataframe/series has the columns 'FinYear' or 'Amount' as these are just text values.  You must specify, for example, `y=invYr.Amount` to specify both the dataframe/series and the column you'd like to graph. The trick here is directly accessing the index of the dataframe.

```
sns.barplot(x=invYr.index, y=invYr.Amount)
```

2) Alternatively, you can specify the data source and then directly refer to its columns.  Note that the grouped data frame had its index reset so that the column again becomes available.

```
sns.barplot(x='FinYear', y='Amount', data=invYr.reset_index())
```

3) A third solution is to specify `as_index=False` when you perform the `groupby`, making the column available in the grouped dataframe.

```
invYr = invoices.groupby('FinYear', as_index=False).Amount.sum()
sns.barplot(x='FinYear', y='Amount', data=invYr)
```

All solutions above produce the same plot below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Alexander this worked perfectly. Still unsure as to why I would have to do that though, why can't the index be called by column name? I also wonder why @BrenBarn solution didn't fix it? Anyway thanks for your help.

Comment: When you perform a `groupby` operation, the default behavior is to index the result on the grouped columns. To avoid this, you can use `invYr = invoices.groupby(['FinYear'], as_index=False).sum()[['Amount']]`. Then you would call `sns.barplot(x=invYr.FinYear, y=invYr.Amount)`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. The only question now is why can't I just type `...x='FinYear', data=invYr...` and instead have to qualify it by typing `x=invYr.FinYear` instead?

Comment: 'FinYear' is just a text label.  If you had another dataframe with that label, there would be a clash because either could be valid (not to mention that Seaborn does not know all the variables that dataframe/series types).  As a programmer, you need to qualify the data to which you are referring.

Comment: "You need to specify the correct datasource for the chart. Seaborn does not know which dataframe/series has the columns 'FinYear' or 'Amount', as these are just text values." The code in the original question clearly specifies `data=invYr`; it is not necessary to pass Series objects to `x` and `y`.